# when changing database local to online page blank

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently made a new database that I had local. Everything worked fine and the scripts I've used (mysql and php codes) have been working properly. Since I've changed the database from local to online it has only caused problems with my script. Of course I've changed the details of connecting to MySQL database (having a password and such). Also, the content after the script won't work either. 
Note: I haven't changed my script AT ALL. I've only changed the connection part.

```
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "dbuser";
    $dbpass = "dbpass";
    $dbname = "compunll_itnj01";

    $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $so = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM besteloverzicht");
    $so->execute();
    --- rest of code
```

[image]
[image]

My apologies if I've forgotten to put anything further here. You can ask me and I'll respond asap!

Comment: Just try adding `ini_set("display_errors",1);` on very top of the page. And see if you could figure out.

Comment: @Rikesh I'm using Wordpress and I'm having a plug-in for using php scripts. I've put your line on the very top of the code but it doesn't seem to work or display any other results

Comment: In that case if you using wordpress, try to turn on your debug to `true` in wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the ip address of your db online

```
$dbhost = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
```